# Calling PHP function with ajax to read file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am taking file input from input type file and calling a javascript function on onchange event like below:

```
<input type="file" onchange="readTheFile(this)">
```

The javascript function is calling a php file containing another PHP function. The javascrit function is:

```
function readTheFile(file){
$.ajax( 
           {
               url: 'readFile.php',
               type: 'GET',
               data: 'fileLoc= '+file,
               success: function(output) 
               {
                   document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = output ;

               }
            }
        ); 
}
</script>
```

I am always getting the error:

```
Warning: fopen( [object HTMLInputElement]) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No           such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\sha\readFile.php on line 3
Unable to open file!
```

content of readFile.php is:

```
<?php
function readFiles($fileLoc){
$file = fopen($fileLoc, "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
while(!feof($file)) {
echo fgets($file);
}
fclose($file);
}

if(isset($_GET['fileLoc'])){
echo readFiles($_GET['fileLoc']);
}
?>
```

Comment: To read file *selected from client's browser. You don't really need to upload file.* if you just want to show content and no further usage. You can just use javascript to read file and show content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the FILE API method (moderns browsers only)

See http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Example:

```
<input type="file" id="files" />

<script>
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

      var reader = new FileReader();

      // Closure to capture the file information.
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
          alert(e.target.result);
        };
      })(f);

      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

**[Live example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Zq3at/)**

Comment: Can you please suggest me edit in my code.. I want to read the file in this way only. I have already tried your code. It didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

First move the file into the directory,  then your rest function will work.

Here is a jquery plugin to upload file through ajax : [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

This plugin send you the parameter of `$_FILES` to your php file, then first move the file to your directory then use `fopen()` to read and display content.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are making a malformed request. According to the documentation, it says the data option is appended directly onto the url for GET requests. I dont think this is likely because you are hitting the correct php script.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Try changing to

```
function readTheFile(file){
$.ajax( 
           {
               url: 'readFile.php',
               type: 'GET',
               data: { fileLoc: file },
               success: function(output) 
               {
                   document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = output ;

               }
            }
        ); 
}
```

Also, I dont see where you are pulling the $fileLoc variable from the $_GET array. It might simply be excluded from your code.